# Landingpage URL with SAP / Custom Domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

By default, published landingpages will become the url pub.[stack].exacttarget.com/xyz

When using a custom domain / SAP i.E. example.com will the landingpage still be pub.example.com or can we actually change the prefix? Are there any others prefixes that will be added i.E. in cases of link trackings in E-Mails? Can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check with Support on customisation of the subdomain you host pages on. The old Landing Pages/Microsites was very versatile in terms of branding of domains used for hosting and I suspect this would be true for Cloud Pages, too. But check with them.

Of what I've seen recently, when configured, the default subdomain used for hosting pages seems to be "cloud.".

Link tracking and personalisation are passed in the "qs" query string parameter created when using the CloudPages URL AMPScript function, rather than added as any form of prefix to the URL to your landing page.

[image]